# How to view the site activity log?

Tags: support

Where can I view a log of how many questions and answers are posted per day on a graph displaying time on the x-axis and the information I'm after on the y-axis (and see how this has changed over a week, month, or even over several years)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Become a moderator
2. https://android.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics

Alternatively, you could run queries on Data Explorer to get the information you want.

Comment: The link is broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: @JohnSonderson Did you follow step 1?

Comment: OK, but I am not a moderator. How can I become a moderator if I do not have enough points? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson I've obviously been too obtuse, my apologies.  The information is private and restricted to elected/appointed moderators.  We can provide and discuss a summary of the information, but not the specifics you're looking for.  If it would serve some useful purpose for the site, rather than just curiosity, we may be able to help.

Comment: Well, just noticed I was receiving less responses in the past couple of days, and began to wonder why this would be. That's all. Thanks.